Windows 11 wireless clients get rejected by NPS due to untrusted certificate chain
Our customer has an 802.1X wireless network that's working fine for Windows 10 computers but not working at all for Windows 11 computers. The Win 11 computers get rejected from the NPS server with the error:
Reason Code:     265
Reason:          The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

The wireless hardware is Unifi APs connected to various flavors of Cisco and DLink enterprise switching and managed by the Unifi Network Controller ver 8.1.127. The certs are all from the AD Certificate Services infrastructure of a root CA kept offline and an issuing CA, both Server 2019, that autoenrolls both domain users and domain computers. The autoenroll and wireless connection is controlled by Group Policy with the effect that the computer is authenticated immediately after connecting to the wireless network, allowing the user to authenticate to the domain immediately after firing up their laptop.
We tried migrating the NPS server to Server 2022, tried different computer manufacturers, compared the root, intermediate and client certs, checked them over for required parameters using this Microsoft resource - all certs check out, but Win 11 clients get rejected.
We can get the Win 11 clients to attach to the wireless using the client login, but that defeats the computer connection that allows the end user to log in to the domain directly.
I'm considering trying a different RADIUS solution than NPS to see if there's some way to get these machines back to authenticating properly, even if I have to divide the RADIUS chores between NPS for user creds and some other solution for machine creds. I'm also looking at the certificate templates to see if any updates or changes there might help.
Looking for any thoughts on what else might be the problem, any ideas on other RADIUS solutions, or perhaps any "this is happening to me, too!"
